# Typescript : How to use callbacks properly

Tags: typescript

I have a method like below.

```
public check(uid, callBack: (msg: string, state: boolean) => void) {
     //some other code
}
```

I want to make sure that whoever calls `check`, also declares types likes below.

```
check('uid here', (msg:string, state:boolean)=>{
     /good
});
```

But the following also works without throwing errors.

```
check('uid here', (msg:string)=>{
     // bad
});
```

Anyway to enforce all params of the callback are declared?

Comment: A decent code checker would complain about *`Unused variable 'state'`* in the callback if the callback is not going to use it. What's the point of forcing it to declare it then? The signatures are *compatible* either way.

Answer (score 4):

About the example with just the string parameter: it's a totally valid callback, you don't have to list the parameter if you don't use it inside your callback. You can avoid unused function parameters that way. Even the following will be valid:

```
check('uid here', () => {
    // your callback
})
```

You will have problems if the arguments differ, so in the following example you will get an error:

```
check('uid here', (somethingReallyBad: object) => {
   // Types of parameters 'something' and 'msg' are incompatible.
   // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'object'.
})
```

Answer (score 2):

No, as far as I know there is no way to enforce callbacks to define all params. That is actually fine - it is quite safe to skip arguments you not going to use in your callback.

TS checks the types of callback args, if callback declares them and use in its body. E.g. as mentioned in other answer:

```
// incompatible type, error!
check('uid here', (wrongType: number) => {

});
```

I don't see much sense on forcing callback devs to list all args even they don't care about them.

```
// I want just print some output, why should I type 10+ chars of code
// declaring unused args

check(uid, (msg: string, state: boolean) => {
     console.log('OK');
})

//instead of writing

check(uid, () => console.log('OK'));
```

Comment: It's definitely not fine, why have a structure that can't be enforced. If its supported its ok, but not fine.

Comment: It is fine, because the structure is enforced at the moment you call the callback.

Comment: @Relm The function signature must merely be *compatible*. Typescript *will* complain when it finds *incompatible* signatures.

Answer (score 1):

I'm puzzled by this too, it seems that the type is only enforced at the moment you call the callback:

```
type StateCallback = (msg: string, state: boolean) => void


function checkTwo(uid: string, callBack: StateCallback) : void {
    // this is not allowed!
    callBack()

    // you have to use the params of StateCallback
    callBack("hi!", true)
}


let cb: StateCallback = () => { console.log("hi") }
checkTwo("boink", cb)
```

It's a bit strange that you can define `cb` without the `string` and `boolean` params. 
When you call `cb()` it still expects those parameters!

When you want to actually use `msg` and `state` in your callback, you do have to define them:

```
let cb2: StateCallback = (msg:string) => { console.log(msg) }
checkTwo("boink", cb2)

let cb3: StateCallback = (msg: string, state:boolean) => { console.log(msg, state) }
checkTwo("boink", cb3)
```